# Conditionally limit to 1 cart item from a particular product subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, cart

I found this code which limits to buy only one product, but I wonder if there is possible to change it, so customer could buy only one product from the certain subcategory.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

return $cart_item_data;
}
```

So if customer add a new product to the cart from this particular product subcategory, it will check if there is already in cart an item from this product subcategory and will remove it if is the case, keeping the fresh added product.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated *(october 2018)*

The hook **`woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`** used in your code and `$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();` that will empty completely all cart items, are not appropriated for what you are asking. Also this code is some kind of oldish.

To get what you need instead try this code (you have to set your subcategory slug to get it work):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'one_subcategory_cart_item', 10, 1 );
function one_subcategory_cart_item( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Set HERE your subcategory (can be an ID, a slug or the name)
    $subcategory       = 't-shirts';
    $count_subcategory = 0;

    // First cart loop: Counting number of subactegory items in cart 
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
        if( has_term( $subcategory, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $count_subcategory++;

    // Second cart loop: Removing subcategory items if more than one (keeping the last one)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if( $count_subcategory > 1 ) {
            $cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code is tested and fully functional.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*